# Weird CentOS server behavior time zones

Tags: linux, centos6, timezone

I have purchased a CentOS 6.8 dedicated server to migrate from shared hosting, and I'm having trouble with the time zones not displaying properly.

I have changed the `php.ini` time zone to `Europe/Dublin` - it didn't work

I have changed the `httpd.conf` timezone to `Europe/Dublin` - it didn't work

And I am trying to change the actual CentOS timezone and this is where it gets weird. I changed time zone to `Europe/Dublin` from `CST` (which was the default), and it seems to think that `Europe/Dublin` is `GMT+14`.

Please see the image link below. The second date should have said Sat Jan 7 07:48:11 GMT 2017.

[image: Weird server time zone situation]

Comment: In the future, please copy-paste the text from the terminal rather than a screenshot of it.

Comment: One of the goto commands for NTP is   ```ntpq -p``` which prints out the current variance from the configured NTP servers.  This can be helpful.

Comment: Your time zone is correct; it is your time that is wrong.

Comment: @MichaelHampton we figured that out just after you went to bed ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The CST time zone is GMT -6, so if CST time is 15:47 then GMT time is 21:47.

If you are saying that at the time you took the screenshot the time was supposed to be 07:48 in the morning, then your server time is not correct, and you need to synchronise it.

Run this command to synchronise the time to correct one:

```
ntpdate -s time.nist.gov
```

It is possible you don't have `ntp` installed at all on your server, in which case you need to install it with:

```
yum install ntp ntpdate ntp-doc
```

And start the NTP service to keep the time synchronised with:

```
/etc/init.d/ntpd start
```

Also make sure to set the NTP service to autostart on boot with:

```
chkconfig ntpd on
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the underlying problem is that "CST" is [an ambiguous name for a timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations).  It can stand for Central Standard Time, China Standard Time, and Cuba Standard Time.

```
[me@risby ~]$ export TZ=GMT ; date
Sat  7 Jan 09:21:31 GMT 2017
[me@risby ~]$ export TZ=US/Central ; date
Sat  7 Jan 03:21:31 CST 2017
[me@risby ~]$ export TZ=ROC ; date
Sat  7 Jan 17:21:31 CST 2017
[me@risby ~]$ export TZ=America/Havana ; date
Sat  7 Jan 04:21:31 CST 2017
```

(I'm aware that the ROC is not the PRC, but [they keep the same time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Taiwan), and I can't immediately put my hand on an unambiguously PRC-specific timezone in my `/usr/share/zoneinfo`.)

So I suspect you're thinking that your system clock is in China Standard Time, and thus expecting GMT to be eight hours *behind* that (0748GMT), whereas my guess would be that it is in Central Standard Time, which puts GMT six hours *ahead* of that (2148GMT).  The latter interpretation is consistent with what you've shown us.

So set your system timezone to what you want it to be, preferably using *geographical* timezones rather than *abbreviation-based* ones.  If the system clock is then wrong, set it (preferably using NTP, which is all UTC-based and doesn't embed any of these problems, and which will keep the clock in sync going forward).

Answer (score 1):

This looks ok to me. Dublin (UTC+0) is currently 6 hours ahead of CST (UTC-6). When you carried out the operation the CST time was 15:47. After the operation the time was 21:48. The time difference is correct.

Comment: Yes the difference is correct but I am in Dublin and it is only 09:30AM right now, not 23:30PM which it is now currently saying is GMT time

Comment: Then something else is wrong as the timezones are demonstrably working correctly. Why don't you try setting the time to be correct ?